# Число чаще всего встречающиеся в БД

Tags: mysqli

У меня есть таблица в БД tasks, в ней есть столбец tasks_type состоящий из чисел ,числа могут повторятся неограниченное количество раз, помогите составить запрос, который бы возвращал наиболее часто встречающееся число, и количество повторений.

Comment: Столбец tasks_type каким типом данных у вас является?

Answer (score 0):

Повторы можно получить таким образом

`SELECT tasks_type, count(tasks_type) AS num FROM tasks GROUP BY tasks_type HAVING COUNT( * ) >1`

А наиболее часто встречаемое значение среди повторов так

`SELECT MAX(Total) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM tasks GROUP BY tasks_type HAVING COUNT( * ) >1) AS Maxresult`

[Пример на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35458411/9816116)